# View files in repository browser without ability to change them

Tags: c#, .net, svn

For my C# Application I need a possibility to have some kind of viewer/filemanager, which displays all Folder and Files of a certain Svn Projekt with the possibility to view their content, but without the possibility to change them.

Our Svn Repository is accessible via svn://ip Adress.
I tried Tortoise Svn with the command "TortoiseProc.exe /command:repobrowser /path:" + "\"" +  + "\" /closeonend:1", but here the user can change Files with the context menu "open" or "edit". This must not happen.

So I ask here, which possibility (with less effort) are possible, ideally to call an existing external program from my application to have a "view only repository browser", which acts like a filemanager similar to explorer to open folders/files to view their content?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Redmine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redmine), a project management software, could be a solution. You typically attach a repository to a managed project. You can browse the repository but cannot modify its content.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this application, I do not know how to install and it seems to big for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use your browser. You have already a web server configured to serve the files, so you should be able to just use the repository path in the browser. This allows you to navigate up and down, each file is then downloaded as a local copy without the possibility to upload it then.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If I type in the address box of a browser svn:/ip_adress, in Chrome, this doesn't work at all. And in Firefox, Internet Explorer, it asks to open TortoiseSVN Client (again the SVN Repository Browser).

Comment: @fst You can try using http://ip_address to view in the browser. If you have svn://ip_address chances are you could also be having a http access.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when working with many members there is a need to have a view only repository accessible to all the team members. For that purpose something like [websvn](https://websvnphp.github.io) can be used.

It is one of the many online browser based open source softwares available. For example you can look at the [image: below image].

Answer (score 0):

finally I decided to write a very simple file browser (I list the svn (with "svn list") directories an files and keep them in a tree control). 
For that, I took as base the Codeproject sources from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10834/Filesystem-TreeView

If I want to view a file, I export it to a temp directory and start the process, which opens the file with the default directory and delete the file afterwards.